# Prototype.js Element.update() throws error on IE9

Tags: internet-explorer, html-table, prototypejs, tablerow

My code looks like:

```
var node = parent.insertRow(before);
node = $(node);
node.update('<td>Hello</td><td>Hello</td><td>Hello</td>');
```

It works on IE6, IE7, IE8, Chrome, Firefox, Safari (both Mac and Windows) but not IE9.

IE9 throws a "DOM Exception: INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR (5)" and points in the middle of prototype.js to e.setAttribute(c,f).  I used the watch window which shows c as "{}" which doesn't make any sense to me.

I'm using Scriptaculous 1.9.0 which includes Prototype 1.7 which all research shows as IE9 compatible.

I know that IE has special requirements for tables which is why I use 
[a Element#update](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/element/update).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If methods are added to Object.prototype, they may need to be made unenumerable using defineProperty for Element#update to work on IE9.  Element#update is brittle when code modifies Object.prototype.

In my case, a library did something like this:

```
Object.prototype.aFunc = function () {
    return doStuff();
};
```

I special-cased IE9 to fix it like this:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Trident/5") > -1) {
   Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'aFunc', {
      value : function () {
         return doStuff();
      },
      enumerable : false
   });
} else {
    Object.prototype.aFunc = function () {
        return doStuff();
    };
}
```